# How to crop out multiple contours in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Can someone guide me in cropping the contours area I found in **RGB** format?

I am going to separate the `contours` group and save it into area for Recognition.

I am using **C++** with **OpenCV** library.

Is using `ApproxPoly()` the right direction?

Sorry for my bad English as I am not native English Speaker.

Edit: @api5, sorry for the unclear question. I want to extract to contour content for coin recognition. What I am trying to implement is crop out as many background as I can before I use Hough Circle Transform to detect the coin.

While separating the coins is also my goal, I am still trying to configure the erode mask. Maybe I will try to use homomorphic filter so that I dont need to use unmask sharping to improve the coin contrast.

I think I found my lead in Grabcut algorithm. Will be back once it works as I intended.

Original Image

[image: Original Image]

Found Contours image
[image: Found Contours Image]

Comment: Thanks for the help in editting and formating, @Saurabh Bhandari.

Comment: Not sure I get exactly what you want to do? You want to take a contour (like the red one and draw its contents in another image? Or you want to separate the coins when they are grouped together?

Comment: @api5, sorry for the unclear question. I want to extract to contour content for coin recognition. What I am trying to implement is crop out as many background as I can before I use Hough Circle Transform to detect the coin.

While separating the coins is also my goal, I am still trying to configure the erode mask. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: maybe [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html) may help you, it is in python, but you can do it with c++ as well. And may give you a lot of steps forward towards your goal

Comment: Thanks @api5, I look into it.